# UIScrollView or UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory, uiscrollview, chat

I have a chat app which needs to save history (similar to the native SMS app).

Currently I'm using a UIWebView but due to performances issues, I want to switch to native controls.

The easier way would be to use a UIScrollView and just add a custom UIView for every bubble, but I'm not sure how will it work for long conversations.

Assuming I have a long history, will UIScorllView perform well? My other option is to use a UITableView but it's an additional overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell wich holds the bubble.

Something similar is done in this [sample project](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/PushChatFull.zip) taken from this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2)